# Filter Firebase Data with Angular5 Pipe

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2, angular-pipe

I am trying to figure out how to filter Firebase data I have pulled to my webpage based on an input fields value. For now filtering by just the name is fine. Right now I am trying to accomplish this with an Angular5 pipe to filter the results. This is what I have so far:

[image]

HTML:

```html
<div class="theoremsContainer">
  <input [(ngModel)]="searchText" class="bibleSearchBar" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
    <ul appScrollable (scrollPosition)="scrollHandler($event)">
      <li id="listElements" *ngFor="let theorem of bibleObservable$ | bibleFilter : searchText | async">
        <div class="theoremContainer" [style.background-color]="setBackgroundColor(theorem.type)">
          <h1 class="theoremTitle">{{theorem.rule}}: {{theorem.name}}</h1>
          <h2 class="theoremType">{{theorem.type}}</h2>
          <p class="theoremEquation">{{theorem.eq}}</p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Typescript:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, AfterContentChecked } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { BibleService } from './bible.service';
import {FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';
declare var MathJax: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bible',
  templateUrl: './bible.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bible.component.scss']
})
export class BibleComponent implements OnInit {

  bibleObservable$: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

  constructor(service: BibleService, private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.bibleObservable$ = service.getTheorems(db);
  }

  ngAfterContentChecked(){
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]);
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  scrollHandler(event) {
    if (event === 'top') {
      console.log('Top touched');
    } else if (event === 'top') {
      console.log('Bottom touched');
    }
  }

  setBackgroundColor(type) {
    if (type === 'axiom') {
      return 'lightsalmon';
    } else {
      return '#bee5eb';
    }
  }
}
```

Pipe:

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'bibleFilter'
})
export class BibleFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
    var answer: any[] = [];

    if (!items) return [];
    if (!searchText) return items;

    searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();

    return items.filter(values => {
      for (let i in values) {
        if (values[i]["name"]) {
          answer.push(values[i]["name"].toString().toLowerCase());
        }
      }
      console.log("ANSWER: " + answer);
      console.log(answer.includes(searchText));
      return answer.includes(searchText);
    });
  }

}
```

Right now my answers array in my pipe is returning an array of strings that are the names of each element but when I type anything into the search bar all elements disappear. What should I do to get the correct Firebase data show on search?

Comment: I would not use a Pipe for this purpose. Instead create an observable stream that filters what is needed. Better yet, one could read only what is needed from firebase.

Comment: Ya that makes more logical sense, is there anything you could point me to on how to do this?

Comment: You already have searchText inside the class, update bibleObservable$ to use an operator like filter to remove what you don't need, something like: bibleObservable$.filter(v => v.includes(searchText)) and use that in the template. This would be a good start.